# I want to summarize my output in a single row based on one column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a result set like
ID product attribute attribute id

| id | product | attribute | attributeid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | A | 1 |
| 1 | x | B | 2 |
| 1 | x | C | 3 |

Now I want my final result set as a single column
let say in case of attribute id 1 I want to populate specific column and for 2 another and 3 another. So My Final output should be like

| id | product | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | A | B | C |

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation while grouping by id, product columns such as

```sql
SELECT id, product, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN attributeid = 1 THEN attribute END) AS attribute1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN attributeid = 2 THEN attribute END) AS attribute2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN attributeid = 3 THEN attribute END) AS attribute3
  FROM t
 GROUP BY id, product
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of problem that `PIVOT` was designed to solve:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
 MAX(attribute)
 FOR attributeid IN (1 AS attribute1, 2 AS attribute2, 3 AS attribute3)
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, product, attribute, attributeid) AS
SELECT 1, 'x', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'x', 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'x', 'C', 3 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | ID | PRODUCT | ATTRIBUTE1 | ATTRIBUTE2 | ATTRIBUTE3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | x | A | B | C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=93ccd56d074e63eee902ed9460a340da)*